# Only clear part of console window

Tags: c#, console-application

My console window looks like this:

```
YES
YES
NO
YES
NO
NO
YES
DOING THE ACTION
ACTION HAS BEEN DONE
ACTION HAS BEEN DONE
```

The yes and no's are random and change every X seconds. I currently just use `Console.Clear();` for clearing the console but this clears the entire console. I only want to clear the yes and no's and let the rest of the lines be. Is there a way to do this?

Edit: I forgot to add that every time it refreshes there are maybe a few yes and no's more or less.

Comment: I suggest clear entire window and write necessary lines again.

Comment: @Ham3d This will make the screen flicker unnecessarily.

Comment: @Ham3d But the lines with action in them have to stay and just add up.

Comment: you can save action lines in a collection and after clearing the screen iterate over it and write action lines again.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the position where you want to write your text and overwrite those values with spaces. For example:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 6);
Console.Write("   ");
```

Comment: This will create some empty lines instead of removing `yes/no` lines.

Comment: This works good, but not perfectly. I forgot to add that every time it refreshes there are maybe a few yes and no's more or less.

Comment: @Ham3d Perhaps you need to try it out before saying that.

Comment: @jel Not sure what you mean?

Comment: @DavidG I mean that the first time it writes maybe 4 lines of yes and no's, after it refreshes there are 9 lines, after that 6, etc. The number of lines with yes and no's are variable so i can't just put line 1 - 4 in the setCursorPosition because then I might remove the wrong number of lines.

Comment: @DavidG But it is a random number of lines, I never know how much it is going to be. I can't interrupt the progress to write new lines of code every time it refreshes either.

Comment: You need to know what area to clear or this won't work.